# JUnit that fails when debugged is correct

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I've a project with some JUnit tests, when I try to run the project with mvn clean install package -X -e I get an erro saying that there's some problems with the tests, here's the error that appears:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.937 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-17T08:31:54+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project risk-business-admissions: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project risk-business-admissions: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.DefaultReporterFactory.runCompleted (DefaultReporterFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.DefaultReporterFactory.close (DefaultReporterFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:740)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:682)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:648)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:586)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

But if I run the project as JUnit test all the tests runs well and there is no errors. When I read the surfire-reports logs a test appears as if it's failing:

```
Tests run: 21, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.789 sec <<< FAILURE!
testObligatoryParameterIdNull(com.bbva.ergo.riskbusinessadmissions.facade.v0.SrvCreateFinancialStatementRiskAnalysisTest)  Time elapsed: 0.033 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: com.bbva.jee.arq.spring.core.servicing.gce.BusinessServiceException
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

But if I run that specific test it works as intentended, here's the JUnit test.

```
public class SrvCreateFinancialStatementRiskAnalysisTest {

    @Mock
    ISrvIntRiskBusinessAdmissions srvIntRiskBusinessAdmissions = new SrvIntRiskBusinessAdmissions();

    @InjectMocks
    ISrvRiskBusinessAdmissionsV0 srvRiskBusinessAdmissionsV0 = new SrvRiskBusinessAdmissionsV0();

    @Mock
    BusinessServicesToolkitManager businessToolKit;

    public FinancialStatementEvaluation evaluation;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        evaluation = FactoryCreateFinancialStatementRiskAnalysis.factoryFinancialStatementEvaluation();
    }

    @Test(expected = BusinessServiceException.class)
    public void testObligatoryParameterIdNull() {
        evaluation.setId(null);
        srvRiskBusinessAdmissionsV0.createFinancialStatementRiskAnalysis("2019060EAI", "ES0182002030251", "AqRWQ111XX",
                evaluation);
    }
}
```

The class where the test "fails":

```
public final class ValidatorCreateFinancialStatementRiskAnalysis {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ValidatorCreateFinancialStatementRiskAnalysis.class);

    private ValidatorCreateFinancialStatementRiskAnalysis() {

    }

    public static void validateFinancialSatementEvaluationRecord(String riskAssessmentId, String participantId,
            String financialStatementId, FinancialStatementEvaluation evaluation) {

        Validate.notNull(riskAssessmentId, "riskAssessmentId");
        Validate.notEmpty(riskAssessmentId, "riskAssessmentId");

        Validate.notNull(participantId, "participantId");
        Validate.notEmpty(participantId, "participantId");

        Validate.notNull(financialStatementId, "financialStatementId");
        Validate.notEmpty(financialStatementId, "financialStatementId");

        if(evaluation == null) {
            throw new BusinessServiceException("mandatoryParametersMissing", "financialStatementEvaluation");
        }

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<FinancialStatementEvaluation>> violations = validator.validate(evaluation);
        for (ConstraintViolation<FinancialStatementEvaluation> violation : violations) {
            LOG.info(violation.getMessage() + ": " + violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
            throw new BusinessServiceException(violation.getMessage(), violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
        }

    }
}
```

I'm using javax.validation to validate my parámeters, ¿any idea why I'm getting  an error when the tests are correct?

Comment: probably because you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: I knwo that I've a NullPointerException, the problem is that all the tests are correct.

Comment: Which version of java and maven-surefire do you use in your project? It might be a bug in the maven-surefire-plugin that occures when using the JDK10 like described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1439) or [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1513).

Comment: I use JDK 8, and 3.0.0-M3 maven-surefire version

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this test:

```
@Test(expected = BusinessServiceException.class)
public void testObligatoryParameterIdNull() {
```

You are expecting it to throw `BusinessServiceException`. Basically saying "this test **must** throw this exception, otherwise it's a test failure". But it doesn't throw it and just runs fine.

Either check your logic to see why it's not throwing the exception, or remove `(expected = BusinessServiceException.class)`.

Comment: Nope, when I debug the test it always throws BusinessServiceException and if I run the test alone it passes with no problem